how to change GOPATH in vs code?
if you enter the command "go evn" in vs, it shows that GOPATH=C:\Users\user\go.
if I want to change GOPATH in vs code, how do I do it?
The book I'm reading says: set GOPATH="C:\code"
I write "set GOPATH=" in the terminal, and then the path to another folder on the desktop, but GOPATH does not change.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
